# Wordpress custom css doesn't load on iOS

Tags: ios, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I tried to customize the css of a child theme.

If I modify the `style.css` of the child theme, it will be commented out on iOS devices.
I tried then to enqueue a new stylesheet, and the result is that this stylesheet doesn't appear at all in the `head` section (always on iOS, the desktop version works like a charm).

This is my code to enqueue the stylesheet:

```
function wp_enqueue_styles() {
    $handle       = 'custom_style';
    $path         = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/';
    $directory    = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/css/';
    $dependencies = [];
    $version      = '1.0';

    $filename     = 'main.css';
    $filename_min = 'main.min.css';

    if ( file_exists( $directory . $filename_min ) ) {
        wp_register_style( $handle, $path . $filename_min );
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $path . $filename_min, $dependencies, $version );
    } else if ( file_exists( $directory . $filename ) ) {
        // override version with file changed time to bypass cache problems
        wp_register_style( $handle, $path . $filename );
        wp_enqueue_style( $handle, $path . $filename, $dependencies, $version );
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try that

```
function theme_name_scripts() {
    // Remove a CSS file (main theme)
    wp_deregister_style( 'Script_name_id' );
    // Add New a CSS file ( child theme )
    wp_enqueue_style( 'Script_name_id', get_template_directory_uri() . 'Script_path',[],null);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```